# Jquery validation in hidden 'div'

Tags: jquery, html, validation, jquery-plugins, jquery-validate

I am new to Jquery. I am working in a **form** with 14 fields

**First 7 fields are visible** and **next 7 are toggled on the basis of a button click in a div** now in total there are **7 fields** which are **'required'**. **3** from first 7(visible part) and 4 from toggling div.

The problem is that when the toggling div is visible JQuery's validation plugin shows the required message if I **miss any of the 7 fields** but the same plugin just checks the validation of only **3** fields (which are in **visible part** of the **form**) when the div is hidden[image: This is the normal condition].

how to make make the **validation of full form** even when the part of the **form** is **hidden**
[image: this is condition 2]
Now if I delete the value of text box **Address 1** and hides the **Address Part** and click **SAVE** it will not prompt for **required** thing for **Address 1** even when I kept it **'required'**

Comment: How are the inputs hidden? Are you sure the elements exist at all when they're hidden?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The possible reason can be that there is `ignore: ':hidden'` line in `jquery.validate.unobtrusive.js` file. Just remove that line.

After 1.9.0 version it was default behaviour. If the line doesn't exists in file(I'm not sure) you can fix that manually by adding

```
$.validator.setDefaults({ ignore: [] });
```

As you can see [here](http://bassistance.de/2011/10/07/release-validation-plugin-1-9-0/)

> Another change should make the setup of forms with hidden elements
>   easier, these are now ignored by default (*option “ignore” has
>   “:hidden” now as default*). In theory, this could break an existing
>   setup. In the unlikely case that it actually does, **you can fix it by
>   setting the ignore-option to “[]” (square brackets without the
>   quotes).**

Comment: Great it started working but how can I make visible the div that is hidden. 
I mean right now the form is not submitting because the value is **not filled** but the div is in hidden state.

Comment: You can programmatically show hidden div when validation error has thrown.